# Introducing non-linear DC offset and enveloping audio asymmetrically

Tags: audio

I'd like to experiment with audio by moving the DC line higher or lower, stretching everything from the highest bit to middle and from middle to the lowest bit, not just move the whole waveform like DC offset tools do. Also, I'd like to try clipping the audio below and above the middle line of the waveform. Is there any software that can do this?

Visually, it should look something like this:

[image]

1. Normal waveform;
2. Ordinary DC offset;
3. The kind of offset I'm talking about;
4. Cut the waveform below middle bit.